# ¿Cómo meter valores de array de consulta en un objeto al recorrer con foreach associativo?

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código, genera una consulta a una tabla, hago la petición con AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../models/consulta_subcredito.php',
    data: {
        numero_subcredito: numero_subcredito,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
}).done((response) => {
    if (response.existe_subcredito == 0) { 
        reject(response.mensaje_consulta);
    } else {
        resolve("Número de sub crédito encontrado en la consulta realizada ¡Revísalo!");
    }
}) . . . // sigue fail();
```

Este es mi script PHP (consulta_subcredito.php) donde se recibe "numero_subredito" y hace la consulta a la base dados

```
$conexion_db_workspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
$sentencia = $conexion_db_workspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare(
    "SELECT num_cre, num_sub, nom_deu, DATE_FORMAT(fech_asig, '%d de %m de %Y') AS fech_asig, rfc_deu, buck_deu, DATE_FORMAT(fech_ult_pag, '%d de %m de %Y') AS fech_ult_pag, FORMAT(mont_ult_pag, 2) AS mont_ult_pag, FORMAT(tot_mas_cons, 2) AS tot_mas_cons, FORMAT(ven_mas_cons, 2) AS ven_mas_cons, FORMAT(ven_cons, 2) AS ven_cons, FORMAT(tot_cast, 2) AS tot_cast, FORMAT(ade_cont_cast, 2) AS ade_cont_cast, FORMAT(ade_cons_cast, 2) AS ade_cons_cast, ref_ban, est_deu, prod_deu, dir_calle, dir_col, dir_mun, dir_est, agen_asig, gru_deu FROM bujic_workspace.mexgas_deudores WHERE num_sub = :numeroSubcredito"
    );
$sentencia -> bindParam(':numeroSubcredito', $numero_subcredito, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sentencia -> execute(); // Aquí manda llamar método execute()

$array = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Obtiene resultado de manera assoc

$response = [ // Arreglo con valores por defecto, que hare json_encode_más abajo
    'existe' => 0, // En pos 'existe' si existe tal registro en BD
    'datos' => [], // En pos 'datos' se guarda la información del registro
    'error' => 'Escriba un número de sub crédito para realizar la consulta' // en pos 'error' un mensaje de error (notificación)
];

foreach($array as $key => $value){ // Se recorre $array_fetch_assoc con foreach assoc
if ($value == $_POST['numero_subcredito']) {
    $response['existe'] = 1;
    $response['datos'] = [$key => $value];
    // Aquí es donde no entiendo como meter la información del registro del 
    // sub crédito, que recorra el array  en 
    // $response['existe'] = 1;
    // $response['datos'] = información traida desde DB en consulta;
    // $response['error'] = notificación para si existe registro;
    // de la manera [$key  $value]; me imprime "datos: "num_sub  MG183573""
    $response['error'] = 'Número de sub crédito encontrado en la consulta realizada ¡Revísalo!';
    break; // debería actuar inmediato
}                   }
if ($response['existe'] == 0) { // Manda arreglo con valores en caso que no exista registro en tabla
    // Actualizar error y mensaje de error
    $response['error'] = 'Número de sub crédito no encontrado en la consulta ¡Lo sentimos!';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

No logro meter el array compuesto de manera associativa con la información obtenida en la consulta PDO hacía la BD MySQL (tabla con 23 columnas), no creo que sea con **$response['datos'] = "$key  $value";**, intente también con **$objeto = (object) $array;** siendo "$objeto" el array que se recorre en el foreach.

Tengo varios días aprendiendo sobre $.ajax() y manera de usar bien una responso, tengo otra pregunta parecida aquí:

[Mi otra pregunta, basicamente lo mismo pero con array indexado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/554916/c%C3%B3mo-meter-valores-de-array-de-consulta-en-un-objeto-al-recorrer-con-foreach-as?noredirect=1#comment980670_554916)

En base a los comentarios de masterguru, les dejo la siguiente imagen:

[image: Devtools]

Al parecer si me esta haciendo el array asociativo contenido dentro de $response['datos'] pero solo de una columna que es la "num_sub".
Este o no este el break, se comporta de la misma manera

Primero lo tenía de la manera:

```
$array_assoc_seleccionar_subcredito = $sentencia_seleccionar_subcredito -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$valores['existe_subcredito'] = 0; 
foreach($array_assoc_seleccionar_subcredito as $key => $value){ 
    $valores['existe_subcredito'] = 1;
    $valores[$key] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($valores);
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente y dónde exactamente? PDO tiene forma de obtener los resultados como objeto, así que si necesites un objeto, no uses `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, usa **`PDO::FETCH_OBJ`**. Comprendido eso, ¿cuál es el el problema?

Comment: tu objetivo es meter un objeto dentro de la base de datos?

Comment: Denme un segundo, estoy trantando de poner más información en la pregunta, pero mi objetivo es basicamente guardar el array assoc de la consulta en  $response['datos'] dentro del foreach

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es cambiar esto: `$response['datos'] = "$key  $value";`  por esto:  `$response['datos'] = [$key=>$value];`.  Lo que no entiendo es el `break:` pues lo pones antes de hacer el `echo json_encode` cuando creo que lo debes poner después si ese if es correcto.  Vamos, tengo mis dudas de si `break;` actua enseguida o continua hasta terminar el ciclo actual.

Comment: Por ahí va mi pregunta masterguru, de verdad una disculpa A. Cedano si no se redactar la pregunta, he tratado de mejorar mi pregunta

Comment: Veo que ahora has puesto esto en tu pregunta:  `$response['datos'] = [$key  $value];` cuando yo te decia esto otro:  `$response['datos'] = [$key=>$value];` para que fuera un array asociativo contenido dentro de **$response['datos']**.  Es decir, te falta el simbolo **=>**.  En cuanto al **break**, si actua de immediato entonces nunca hace el `echo json_encode` que aparece más abajo y no manda nada cuando se cumple esa condición... ¿eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: Sí, una disculpa se me olvido el =>, coloque una imagen de lo que me arroja devtools en network al generar la consulta desde UI del usuario, solo me arroja pues una columna la num_sub => 'MG154254' (numero sub crédito)

Comment: Vale, pues cambia el `$response['datos'] = [$key=>$value];` por `$response['datos'] = $array;` para que obtengas todas las columnas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138943/discussion-between-minor-and-masterguru).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo optaría por hacerlo así:

```
$conexion_db_workspace = new conexionBDWorkspace();
$sentencia = $conexion_db_workspace -> conectarBD() -> prepare(
    "SELECT num_cre, num_sub, nom_deu, DATE_FORMAT(fech_asig, '%d de %m de %Y') AS fech_asig, rfc_deu, buck_deu, DATE_FORMAT(fech_ult_pag, '%d de %m de %Y') AS fech_ult_pag, FORMAT(mont_ult_pag, 2) AS mont_ult_pag, FORMAT(tot_mas_cons, 2) AS tot_mas_cons, FORMAT(ven_mas_cons, 2) AS ven_mas_cons, FORMAT(ven_cons, 2) AS ven_cons, FORMAT(tot_cast, 2) AS tot_cast, FORMAT(ade_cont_cast, 2) AS ade_cont_cast, FORMAT(ade_cons_cast, 2) AS ade_cons_cast, ref_ban, est_deu, prod_deu, dir_calle, dir_col, dir_mun, dir_est, agen_asig, gru_deu FROM bujic_workspace.mexgas_deudores WHERE num_sub = :numeroSubcredito"
    );
$sentencia -> bindParam(':numeroSubcredito', $numero_subcredito, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia -> execute(); // Aquí manda llamar método execute()

$array = $sentencia -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Obtiene resultado de manera assoc

if ($array['num_sub'] == $_POST['numero_subcredito']) {
    $response['existe'] = 1;
    $response['datos'] = $array;
    $response['error'] = 'Número de sub crédito encontrado en la consulta realizada ¡Revísalo!';
} else {
    $response = [ // Arreglo con valores por defecto, que hare json_encode_más abajo
        'existe' => 0, // En pos 'existe' si existe tal registro en BD
        'datos' => [], // En pos 'datos' se guarda la información del registro
        'error' => 'Número de sub crédito no encontrado en la consulta ¡Lo sentimos!'
    ];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

de esta forma quitamos el **for** o **foreach** pues no hace falta para acceder a la columna **num_sub** pues `$array` ya es asociativo de por sí, y limpiamos un poco los condicionales dejándolo todo en uno solo.

Comment: ¡Excelente, me ha servido de maravilla, muchas gracias!